# How to align checkboxes for a to do list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, checkbox

I am trying to make a to-do list with html/css/js for my first coding project.
I used js to create a `<li>` element with a checkbox input inside. When I run my code, the checkbox is displayed on the right of the text displayed. I want to make it such that the checkboxes are aligned or styled to the left, but I don't know how to go about this. I am so sorry if this is a very vague qn.

```js
function printInput() {
  var toDoInput = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  var para = document.createElement("li");
  para.innerText = toDoInput;
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.className = "cb";
  para.appendChild(checkBox);
  document.getElementById("paragraph").appendChild(para);
}

function enter() {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("enterButton ").click();
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#paragraph {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcbcc;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1> What will you do today? </h1>
<div class="container">
  <input class="inputBox" id="textbox" type="text" onkeypress="enter()" placeholder="Bake a cake">
  <input onclick="printInput()" class="inputBox" id="enterButton" type="button" value="Enter" id="enterButton">
  <ul id=paragraph></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want align the checkboxes?

Comment: Notice that you first add the test and then the input. If you will create the checkbox and then add the text (using `innerHTML +=` instead of `textContent`) the checkbox will be in the left..

Comment: @O.o  I want to try to make the checkbox all the way to the right of the container so that it is standardized, or to the very left of the container. Sorry I didn't make my qn clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the checkbox after you add text to the element. a text block is also considered a node inside the element. So `para.childNodes` also gives you the text nodes. `para.childnodes[0]` is the added text from the input in your code.

By using `para.insertBefore(checkBox, para.childNodes[0]);` we can add the checkbox before the text node.

`insertBefore` allows you to insert an element before another. `appendChild` always adds (appends) to the end of the nodelist.

*There are other ways of doing this too in the DOM.*

```js
function printInput() {
  var toDoInput = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  var para = document.createElement("li");
  para.innerText = toDoInput;
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.className = "cb";
  //this line will insert the checkbox before the text node
  para.insertBefore(checkBox, para.childNodes[0]);
  document.getElementById("paragraph").appendChild(para);
}

function enter() {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("enterButton ").click();
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#paragraph {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcbcc;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1> What will you do today? </h1>
<div class="container">
  <input class="inputBox" id="textbox" type="text" onkeypress="enter()" placeholder="Bake a cake">
  <input onclick="printInput()" class="inputBox" id="enterButton" type="button" value="Enter" id="enterButton">
  <ul id=paragraph></ul>
</div>
```